# Did the compatibility requirements change?

Tags: pokemon-go, technical-issues

I downloaded Pokemon Go through the google play store in July. With the recent (mandatory) update (august 8, version 0.33) the play store now says "Your device isn't compatible with this version."

The official source for compatibility appears to be [this page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices)

My device is an SM-P900 tablet running android version 5.0.2, which has gps and wifi. My device seems to have roughly 2.7 GB RAM.

Has pokemon go changed to have higher or additional system requirements?

Comment: Have you tried all the regular stuff, like restarting app, restarting device, deleting and reinstalling, etc.?

Comment: @ThePickleTickler I have tried most of that, however I can't reinstall through the play store due to the compatibility issue.

Comment: In the Play Store, Niantic is written that Pokémon Go is "Compatible with Android devices that have 2GB RAM or more and have Android Version 4.4 - 6.0 installed."

Comment: @PythonMaster I hadn't seen the RAM requirement, I don't see it in the store. Regardless I would seem to meet both of those requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Niantic is [rather clear](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nianticlabs.pokemongo) in the Google Play Store:

> - Compatibility with tablet devices is not guaranteed.

For whatever reason, they decided that your tablet does not "work" with the game for whatever reason, and have since blacklisted it from being used on those tablets (even though they meet/surpass the actual requirements for running the game).

I'd contact Niantic Support and ask them why your tablet is explicitly blacklisted. It may very well be a mistake on the part of the last published version of the app.

Comment: If I do have to go the apk route, do you have advice on finding a reputable source?

Comment: Gotta love the meta effect -3 on this complete answer..

Comment: @Insane Some of those were spam flags.

Comment: @Angzuril Check out [this post](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/130010/105562) on Security SE. It should answer your question.